# How to calculate eigenvectors from an identity matrix with eigenvalue $= 1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

When determining the eigenvectors from matrix $A$:
$$
      \begin{pmatrix}
      1 & 0 \\
      0 & 1 \\
      \end{pmatrix}
$$

I found the eigenvalue to be $ \lambda = 1 $

calculating  $ (A - 1*\lambda) $  gives me the matrix :
$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{cc|c}
      0&0&0\\
      0&0&0
    \end{array}
\right] $$

Which eigenvector would this produce?

Comment: What is the solution space for the system related to $\;\det(A-1I)\;$ . The whole space, right?

Comment: The matrix is diagonal.....so the eigenvectors and eigenvalues should be obvious

Comment: @TylerHG Not to someone who is new to the subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $\lambda=1$, the Eigenvector equation is

$$0v=0.$$

This clearly means that any vector is a solution.

---

By the way, this can be found directly by identifying

$$Av=\lambda v$$ and $$Iv=v.$$

Answer (score 0):

You made a small error when calculating your eigenvalues. If you solve for the the determinant equal to zero you end up with the following equation:
$(1-\lambda)(1-\lambda) = 0$.

Solving this you get both eigenvalues of $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 = 1$. You can see from this how a diagonal matrix greatly simplifies your calculations. In a diagonal matrix the diagonal terms are your eigenvalues. Try recalculcating your eigenvectors with these eigenvalues. You will get $[0,\ 1]^T$ and $[1,\ 0]^T$.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly obvious, and can be solved with a bit of intuition without even touching an equation

The basis vector $\vec{i}$ equals $[1,0]^T$
and the basis vector $\vec{j}$ equals $[0,1]^T$.
This means this matrix
$(\vec i,\vec j)$ is the identity matrix. Nothing is changed
because no vector is changed; every (nonzero) vector is an eigenvector with an eigenvalue of $1$.

([Visual](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZHQObOWTQDPD3MizzM2xVFitgF8hE_ab00) Intuition for what's going on)

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  I've taken the liberty to use some MathJax and $\LaTeX$ formatting, and hope that it will encourage you to use similar formatting in future posts to make your points.  See [this introduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).